# React native components are not the same from device to another

Tags: node.js, react-native

so i've been doing react native for a while and after running my app on different devices all the components are not exactly what they are
this is an example :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor:'#F5F5F8'
    },
    tinyLogo: {

        width: 308,
        height: 282,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        alignSelf:'center',
        top: 80

    },
    logo: {
        width: 66,
        height: 58,
    },

    text: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: "#2E3E5C",
        fontSize: 22,
        fontFamily: 'arial',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        width: "100%",
        marginTop:70

    },
    btnContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "#CB5C17",
        height: 60,
        width:327,
        borderRadius: 30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 99


    },
        headline: {

        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 100


    }
    
});
const OnBoarding = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            <Image style={styles.tinyLogo}
                source={require('../assets/TacosLogo.png')} />
            <View style={styles.headline}>
                
                <Text style={styles.text} >HOT AND FRENCH TACOS</Text>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: "#9FA5C0", fontSize: 17, fontFamily: 'arial', fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 16, letterSpacing: 1 }} >The best taste</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.btnContainer} onPress={() =>
                    navigation.navigate('Login')
                }>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', letterSpacing: 0.7, fontFamily: 'arial'}} >Commencer</Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>
                
            </View>

        </View>

        
        
        
        );
}
export default OnBoarding;
```

this is what it looks like on my android device Xiaomi Redmi 9 (6.53') 2340 x 1080 pixels
[image]

and this is what it looks like on other android device Huawei y6 (6.09') 1560 x 720 pixels
[image]

they dont look the same at all , even the dimensions
is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid spacing using hardcoded values like,
`marginTop: 100,`
`marginTop: 99,`
`marginBottom: 70,`

because you want your app to run on different device sizes.

Try Depending more on flexbox `space-between` and other alignment properties, rather than hardcoding the values.
Read more about it from here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Or wrap the content in `ScrollView` component depending on the use case you have.

There is also some libraries that may help you by getting responsive values rather than hardcoded ones.
like: https://github.com/NewBieBR/react-native-normalize
https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen#readme

Comment: Yeah but still not a solution for the Touchableopacity width and height , same values but different look

Comment: Right, There is also some libraries that may help you by getting responsive values rather than hardcoded ones, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much ! that's what im looking for

Comment: My pleasure, glad I helped